# C++ Diamond of Death

Tags: c++, inheritance, diamond-problem

Ok so I understand how to solve the problem of the diamond of death inheritance when you have full control over all the classes but what if you only have control over the last class to inherit from both
So I have this:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};
class D : public B, public C {};
```

and I have no way of editing B and C only D, is there an easy way I can do this?

Comment: Use composition? AFAIK, if you can't modify the declarations to `class B : public virtual A` etc. you are stuck..

Comment: What you've written isn't a diamond, so there's no problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fake it by containment. Have D contain B and C and give D the same public interface as the union of B and C's public interface. 
Then call the appropriate methods of B and C from D's public interface.

Of course you will have a problem casting and polymorphism as it won't follow the laws of inheritance.

In short, there's no good way.

Answer (score 3):

The is a very good reason you can't force `B` and `C` to share `A`. Consider:

```
struct A {int i;};
struct B : A {
 B(){i=3;}
 void foo() {
  //crash if i!=3
 }
};
struct C : A {
 C(){i=4;}
 void bar() {
  //crash if i!=4
 }
};
```

`B` and `C` are good classes. They can't handle a situation that they won't get in (invalid value of i).

If there was a way to do what you ask for (`struct D:B,C`, where `B` and `C` share `A`), what will be the value of `D::A::i`?

virtual inheritance means "I need this class, but I won't require some valid values for it, and I completely fine with somebody else mess with it".

Comment: If `i` is expected to keep its initial value, maybe it should be `const`. And `A` should have a constructor.

Comment: @curiousguy I never said it should keep its initial value. Maybe there is another class E:A that may change i during its running. (If you insist, consider a situation which B needs an odd value, and C needs an even value)

Anyway, all this is irrelevant to my main point: virtual inheritance means "I completely fine with somebody else mess with my A", and if B (and C) didn't say that, it is not a good idea to force them to share A.

Comment: If the variable is indeed variable, then `foo` and `bar` cannot expect that `i` will retain its initial value.